# adding integer column to date column to get 'future date' using python

Tags: python, datetime, days, elapsed

I have a python dataframe with a 'date' column with ~200 elements in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

I have a 2nd column (in the same dataframe) with the number of days (these days vary...sometime 1, sometime 360), but always integers.

I want to add the two up.

The date column is of type datetime64 [ns], and 'days' column is type int64.

truely stuck.  I Can find lots of examples where the days are constant, but nothing where the days are in a column.

Please help.

Comment: You want to add the numbers with the dates so that it shows a new date or you just want to add them as strings - just to be placed side by side.

Comment: hi instinct 246.  I want to add to show new date.  thanks.

Comment: Have posted an answer - please check if it resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?  Pandas has its own date time and timedelta module to make things easier.

**Sample Dataframe:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates_Col':['2019-12-15','2020-01-14','2020-03-19','2020-06-17','2019-08-12'], 'Days':[2,15,70,28,3]})
df
```

**O/P**

[image]

**Code** to add days from second column to the first column:

```
df['Dates_Col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates_Col']) #Convert the first column to pandas datetime type
df['Dates_Col'] = df['Dates_Col']+pd.to_timedelta(df['Days'],unit='d') #Convert the second column type to pandas timedelta type and add to first column (which is already in date time type)
df
```

**O/P**

[image]

Comment: instinct246: A very BIG thank you!!!  This was exactly what I needed.  Much appreciated.

Cheers!!

-Big_Ears

Comment: @Big_Ears Can : In that case, can you please 'Accept' the answer? Mind up-voting if this gives an efficient solution to you ? :)

Comment: hi instinct246...how do I accept the answer?  is there a button to push...sorry very new on this site.

Comment: Beside my answer there will be an 'accept' option... And you can see up arrow and down arrow as well... Up arrow is to upvote...

Answer (score 1):

[date.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) is what you are after

you can use this to specify the number of days (or other time/date increments)

```
date = datetime.date(2030, 2, 2)
days = datetime.timedelta(2)
print(date + days)
```

Alternatively, if you are using numpy, [timedelta](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic) will do the same conceptual thing for a datetime64 type

Comment: can the timedelta(2) by timedelta(df[days column])?

Comment: It depends on the framework you are using as to how to specifically implement this. What are you using?